# Como remover todos nós de uma lista circular?

Tags: c, c++, lista, estrutura-de-dados

Estou tendo dificuldades pra pegar a lógica de como remover todos os nós de uma lista circular, se alguém pudesse dar uma breve explicação de conceito e / ou apontar os erros no código que já fiz ficaria muito grato :

```
int freelist ( Node ** list ) {

    if ( empty ( list ) ) {

        return 0;

    }

    if ( ( * list ) == ( * list ) -> next ) {

        free ( * list );

        ( * list ) = NULL;

        return 1;

    }

    Node * tmp = NULL, * aux = ( * list ) -> next;

    while ( aux != ( * list ) ) {

        tmp = aux;

        aux = aux -> next;

        free ( tmp );

    }

    // ( * list ) = NULL;

    return 1;

}
```

Se a lista contem apenas um item a função funciona perfeitamente, já se mais de um ela não os deleta ... ( Código completo [aqui](http://ghostbin.com/paste/bmxv4) )

Comment: Pode postar o código completo para que possamos reproduzir seu código?

Comment: Ghostbin.com/paste/bmxv4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu construí esse método em C++, porém é fácil você passar ele pra C.

```
    void clean() {

    if (head == NULL) {
        cout << "A lista esta vazia\n";
        return;
    }
    else {

        while (head != tail) {
            Node * aux = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete(aux);
        }

        Node * aux = head;
        head = NULL;
        delete(aux);

        cout << "A lista foi esvaziada\n";

    }

}
```

O `head`  fica responsável por marcar onde a lista circular começa, e o `tail` fica responsável por marcar o ultimo no incluído na lista.

Veja que utilizo uma estrutura de repetição em que eu guardo o nó que quero desalocar em um ponteiro auxiliar, depois eu modifico o `head` (`head` passa a apontar para o próximo no que sera desalocado), e por último um `delete` no endereço que aux guarda para desalocar a memoria.

Perceba que utilizo `delete` ao invés de `free`, pois eu utilizei o operador `new`para criar um no na minha lista em C++. Em C, você utilizará o `malloc` para criar os nos da sua lista, e a função `free` para desalocar a memoria.